# SqlDataProvider cannot resolve resolution path

Tags: postgresql, f#, mono

So I've tried this with .Net Core 2.0 and now with Mono targeting .NET 4.5.  In both cases I get the error

"The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: Unable to resolve assemblies. One of Npgsql.dll must exist in the paths: 
 /Users/mgaff/crypt/test/packages/Npgsql
/Users/mgaff/crypt/test/packages/SQLProvider/lib" . I copied the path to the dll in VS Code and am using it as the resolution path but the data provider is not seeing it.  The below example is pretty much copied from https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/postgresql.html.  Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks

```
let [<Literal>] dbVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL

let [<Literal>] connString = "Host=localhost;Database=mydb;User Id=mgaff;"
let [<Literal>] resPath = 
@"/Users/mgaff/crypt/test/packages/Npgsql/lib/net45/"

let [<Literal>] indivAmount = 1000
let [<Literal>] useOptTypes  = true

type sql =
    SqlDataProvider<
        dbVendor,
        connString,
        "",         //ConnectionNameString can be left empty 
        resPath,
        indivAmount,
        useOptTypes>
```

Comment: My first guess would be that you need a higher version than 4.5 - when an assembly if for a later .NET version, then this is a typical error message. I do not think that .NET Core will work in any case.

Comment: The main point is that you have to compile with Mono and use .NET Core as execution time libraries. See a working sample from: https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/tree/master/tests/SqlProvider.Core.Tests/Postgres

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 4.5 check both the Npgsql version (tl;dr you should use 3.1.10 - see https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/373) and the DLLs architecture (32bit or 64bit).

As state above, some Type Providers doesn't work (yet) in dotnet.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still getting the same error with version 3.1.10.  This is the first time I'm setting up a project in F# and .Net so it could easily be something else I'm doing wrong. As for dotnet core I tried to implement the workaround seen here https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3303, and was able to build but was still dealing with errors with the package. Probably going to just move on and try to get something else up and running.